# My minecraft skin looks semi-transparent, how can I fix it back?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image: Screenshot from the game]

I switched to the 3rd person mode while playing Minecraft and I found out that I look semi-transparent. I tried changing the skin but that didn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: This is part of the snapshot, not part of a stable build. Use a stable build instead if you would like things to work as you expect.

Comment: Depending on the version you are playing or the skin server status, it could be a glitch. Can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: How do you mean "see through"? Depending on your gamemode, this could be the default. [Gamemode 3 or "Spectator" mode](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Spectator) has these as features of this particular game mode.

Answer (score 4):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-93000) with 15w47b. To fix it, upgrade to 15w47c or downgrade to a stable version.